# i can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop and I haven't been able to connect to WiFi yet. It shows that my connection is excellent but when I try to connect it tries to connect for 15 seconds, then says connection lost. WiFi worked when I was running Win8 so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: Please check your current wireless configuration and be sure that Ubuntu has the appropriate wireless drivers installed.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/wCcNRTu6

Comment: There is a bug in the kernel you are using that is causing your issue, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239459 when a solution is stable it will be included in the normal updates you download in ubuntu. there is a patch in the link above but it causes your computer not to shutdown properly,

Comment: How long do you think it will be until the patch comes as a normal update?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when using certain Belkin Wifi adapters since 10.10. I'm not sure what adapter you are using but the fix for me is below, I imagine the fix for your adapter may be similar but will specify a different driver.

Step #1:
In terminal type "sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"

Step #2:
add the line "blacklist rt2800usb" anywhere within. Feel free to add a #Description above it. Click save when done, and reboot.